# Tensor product between Hilbert and Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, random-variables

In several papers on random fields $u(x,\omega)$, where $x$ is a spatial variable $x \in D$, and $\omega \in \Omega$, a natural functional setup involves Hilbert spaces. The question I have is somewhat unrelated to random fields, and it has to do with Tensor products on Banach spaces.

A typical setup in the papers I am reading is to have $u \in L^2(\Omega,H)$, where $H$ is a Hilbert space of functions defined on $D$. Often, it is also used the fact that this space is isomorphic to $L^2(\Omega) \otimes H)$.

I need to mirror this type of construction, but for my application the standard setup is $u \in L^2(\Omega,B)$, where $B$ is a Banach space. We can think of $B = C(D)$, for instance. I would like, in principle, to be able to say that $L^2(\Omega,B) \cong L^2(\Omega) \otimes B$, but I am not in control of the subtleties that this involves, or which norms I should use in the latter space.

Searching for Tensor Products on Banach spaces one bumps into rather abstract literature, and I wonder if you can point me to some results for the case I mention above, or if you have any suggestion at all on what to do.

Comment: Did you mean $L^2(\Omega)\otimes B$?

Comment: Are you sure that $L^2(\Omega,H)\cong L^2(\Omega)\otimes H$ and not $L^2(\Omega,H)\cong L^2(\Omega)\hat{\otimes} H$?

Comment: @CaptainLama yes I meant that, sorry. I have edited the question.

Comment: @Filippo that may well be (and it is partly what my problem is). In most papers that I see on Hilbert spaces the $\hat \otimes$ is not written (presumably because the completion is implied?).

Comment: @DanSemiotovic "presumably because the completion is implied?" - Probably, but I don't consider it a good idea to denote the tensor product and its completion by the same symbol :)

Comment: Fair enough @Filippo. Is there any results you are aware of when there is a Banach space instead of the Hilbeet space (with completion)?

Comment: @DanSemiotovic Unfortunately not, but since a Hilbert space is a complex Banach space with the norm induced by an inner product, many results for Hilbert spaces are probably true for all complex Banach spaces. Since most people only care about Hilbert spaces, they don't bother to make this distinction. This is not unusual: Most results in DG are formulated for smooth manifolds, even though differentiability is often enough. I'm afraid you'll have to look into the proof of$$L^2(\Omega,H)\cong L^2(\Omega)\otimes H$$and see if it exploits the fact that the norm is given by an inner product.

Comment: @DanSemiotovic One more comment: While the tensor product of two inner product spaces is another inner product space (i.e. there is a preferred inner product on the tensor product), there is no obvious norm on the tensor product of Banach spaces. I guess that's good reason to only consider Hilbert spaces. Anyways, I recommend you have a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_tensor_product) Wikipedia article.

Comment: Yes, I saw that before asking the question, as I do not find that article helpful. But thank you very much for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 2):

As a reference, I suggest "Tensor norms and operator ideals" by Defant and Floret. In Section 7 you find your desired result: For $1 \le p < \infty$ and a normed space $B$, there is a natural norm on the algebraic tensor product $L^p(\mu) \otimes B$, such that the completion of this space coincides with $L^p(\mu; \tilde B)$, where $\tilde B$ is the completion of $B$.